# jsonschema: error: argument schema: invalid _json_file value

Tags: python, json

I am trying to validate my json schema in command line using the jsonschema python package and I get the error:

> jsonschema: error: argument schema: invalid _json_file value

I don't understand the error as I have valid json file which I tested in  myjson.com and tried with jsonview in Chrome.
Has any one had similar issues, and if so, what does this mean?!

```
{
"id": "http://test.com/models/reg.json"
"description": "schema for register",
  "register": {
    "type": "object",
    "name": {"type": "string"},
    "groups": {
      "type": "object",
      "primary": {"type": "string"},
      "secondary": {
        "type": "array",
      }

    },
    "title": {"type": "string"},
    "attribute": {"type": "string"},
    "configuration": {"type": "string"}

  }

}
```

Comment: You stated "I have valid json file". Fine, but what does it look like? Unless you provide us with a [mcve] (incuding this JSON file), how could "we" possibly assist you in solving this particular problem?

Answer (score 1):

Attempting `json.loads(your_input_string)`:

You have a missing comma after the `.json"` right up the front.
`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 3 column 1 (char 42)`

Fixing that, we move along to
`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 12 column 7 (char 280)`

This happens in  `"secondary": {"type": "array", }` (whitespace compressed). That comma should not be there. Python allows it; JSON doesn't.

No further errors.

Note: Same results using myjson.com (except that myjson tells you only that you have an error, not what, not where). Suggested: use Python for error detection